# laço arq.readlines python / tkinter

Tags: python

Sou novo em Python e estou fazendo um relatório e não estou conseguindo fazer um laço para ler um arquivo txt que eu tenho.

os dados do arquivo txt são:
('001','0:59:30.0','1','3.00')
('002','0:59:30.0','2','4.00')
('003','0:59:30.0','3','5.00')
('004','0:59:30.0','4','6.00')
('005','0:59:30.0','5','7.00')
quero que o laço só termine quando a ultima linha for escrita, coloquei os 5 primeiros itens da lista.

O formato que eu quero deixar é numa lista relattxt como demonstrado abaixo

```
relattxt = [('001', '0:59:30.00', '1', '3.00'),
            ('002', '0:59:30.00', '2', '4.00'),
            ('003', '0:59:30.00', '3', '5.00'),
            ('004', '0:59:30.00', '4', '6.00'),
            ('005', '0:59:30.00', '5', '7.00')]
```

sei que preciso usar o comando

```
arq = open(f'relatorio.txt', 'r')
texto = arq.readlines()
```

posso também mudar o formato dos dados do txt para ficar mais fácil
por favor, me ajudem
obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("relatorio.txt") as arquivo:
    relattxt = [literal_eval(linha) for linha in arquivo]
```

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado